# Why Exception occured getting address of COM function?

Tags: c#, com, interop, vtable, typelib

I am getting the address of a COM function by loading type library (TLB) and iterating over types using `ITypeLib` and `ITypeInfo`.
After calling the `AddressOfMember` function of ITypeInfo I am facing the following exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800288BD): Wrong module kind for the operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800288BD (TYPE_E_BADMODULEKIND)) at System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.ITypeInfo.AddressOfMember(Int32 memid, INVOKEKIND invKind, IntPtr& ppv).

How do I get rid of this exception?

Comment: Are you sure the interface you are trying to get the address on supports vtable binding at all?

Comment: I've given it IDispatch dual interface implemented COM component still fails. More over My all interfaces inherited from IUnknown and when GetNames(..) given me "QueryInterface" , it get failed here as well and here FUNCDESC.memid (some e.g 1245781) seemed wrong.
I am strange every thing enumerated properly with ITypeInfo and all other structures but AddressOfMember fails to deliver address

Comment: I think all IUnknown binded COM components are vtabled binded.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, haven't done this type of thing before, but you say you are loading the tlb file?  It might be that for addressofmember you need to load the dll that contains the com object,  I thought the tlb file was just a description of the interfaces, and thus addressofmember wouldn't have any code to load.